# Youtube API User can upload video to owner youtube channel from website

Tags: video, youtube-api, authorization

Just wondering what the best way would be to create a web applications where the user can directly upload/add videos to my youtube channel/account. I know I have to use the youtube api.. I can get my web applications to ask for my details and pull my videos from my account.. I want the web applications to be constantly logged into my account and users can add videos freely and then being moderated by my self from youtube..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this via [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/).

Users will still upload into their account, this way your account will be free from getting suspended due to alleged videos if any.

But all those videos, once uploaded, will appear in your moderation. Once approved by you, they will be added in your playlist.